# is there any way to develop roku tv application not using brightscript?

Tags: javascript, android, roku, television, brightscript

I have some questions about developing a Roku TV application.
I have my web application with HTML, javascript and java.
I have read Roku docs already, but I couldn't find any way developing my application through
WebView like Android TV.
Actually I have no time to study brightscript and develop my application again...

So my questions are :

1. Is brightscript the only way to develop Roku TV applications?
2. Can javascript be used in brightscript?

Thank you for reading my question.
I'm really looking forward to positive answers...:-(

Comment: Roku isn't Android.  Why do you think it even has a WebView type class available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of you question as of now, **BrightScript** is the only and only way for developing Roku applications. If you don't have time to study BrightScript, refrain yourself from developing roku applications.